# How to set ID value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [User_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
    [LogIn] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Pass] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,

)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Consecutives]
(
    [Consecutives_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL,

)
```

I'm being asked to be able to set an edit the `User_ID` that is going to be used next when adding a new user using the value stated on the `Consecutive` table.

So if for example the `Consecutive` value is 50, even if the last user added has the `User_ID` set to 8 the new user's ID will be 50 and the consecutive updated to 51.

I would do it using a foreign key, but obviously I can't set a primary key to be a foreign key.

I can't find a way to do this.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: So the `Users` and the `Consecutives` have a one-to-one relationship? Why not have just a single table for them?

Comment: I have other tables where this also applies(I just wanted to have one example), so I need to be able to have different values on the `Consecutives` table

Comment: Note that identity columns can't be updated - you can leave it to sql server to generate the value or insert it manually using set identity insert on, but once he row is in the table the identity value can't be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is called a *one-to-one relationship*.
You create such a relationship by connecting both tables with a foreign key referencing their primary keys (or a unique index).
However, since this is a one-to-one relationship, only the main table actually needs the `identity` specification on it's primary key.

Your requirement to insert a record to the `Users` based on an existing record in the `Consecutives` table seems strange to me. Usually, when you have a one-to-one relationship you populate the related records in both tables in the same transaction.

To create a one-to-one relationship, where `Consecutives` is the main table, Your DDL should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Consecutives]
(
    [Consecutives_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Consecutives PRIMARY KEY (Consecutives_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [User_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LogIn] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Pass] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Users PRIMARY KEY (User_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Users_Consecutives FOREIGN KEY (User_ID) REFERENCES [dbo].[Consecutives]([Consecutives_ID])
);
```

Please note I've removed the `identity` specification from the `User_ID` column, and also changed the way the primary key is declared so that I could name it manually.
Naming constraints is best practice since if you ever need to change them it's much simpler when you already know their names.

Now, to insert a single record to both tables in the same transaction you can create a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertUser
(
    @Name varchar(100),
    @Value int,
    @LogIn varchar(100),
    @Pass varchar(100)
)
AS
    DECLARE @Consecutives AS TABLE
    (
        Id int
    );

    BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Consecutives] ([Name], [Value]) 
    OUTPUT Inserted.Consecutives_ID INTO @Consecutives
    VALUES (@Name, @Value)

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users] ([User_ID], [LogIn], [Pass])
    SELECT Id, @Login, @Pass
    FROM @Consecutives

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLL BACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
GO
```

and execute it like this:

```
EXEC InsertUser 'Zohar Peled', 1, 'Zohar', 'Peled'
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/KKBD96944) (Please note that rextester doesn't allow using transactions so the try...catch and transaction parts are removed from the demo there)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried set identity insert on? [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) may help you. To use the identity insert, the user needs some alter table permissions.